# Developing with Kinect: OpenNi

Tags: kinect, openni

So, i have begun researching about kinect for the company next commercial App.
But then, a question have arisen between the team:

Kinect is maintained by Microsoft, and they they own official SDK that you can use for commercial purposes.
But if we use the OpenNi technology, can we use it to develop a commercial application? Is there anyone developing commercial applications with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OpenNi Nite's [own licencing terms](http://www.primesense.com/solutions/nite-middleware/nite-licensing-terms/) you're not allowed to bundle NITE or sell it with your software.

For further limiting factors, OpenNi is Apache 2.0 licenced (see specs [here](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0))

So in summary, it's possible to use OpenNI / NITE to write a commercial application, but because you are not allowed to bundle NITE, it becomes harder to distribute than it would be with Microsoft's official API.

Comment: I'm sorry, i should have accepted your answer some time ago. I went away from stack for a while. Our application has not yet reached full-scale development. Thanks for the clarification; That helped.

Comment: Don't sweat it. :) glad i could help.